# Integrating Flask-Python with HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

In my code , I want the Javascript defined in index.html page to run when a particular condition in app.py is true, else the script should not run. How can I achieve this?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/',methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
    #print "came here"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_token = request.args.get("validationtoken")
        print "search", search_token
        if search_token != None:
            # text = search_token
            resp = Response(search_token, status=200, mimetype='plain/text')
            print "resp",resp
            return resp
        else:
             print " Notification received "
             ##### HERE I NEED TO CALL THE Java SCRIPT DEFINED IN HTML PAGE TO EXECUTE


    elif request.method=="GET":
         code=request.args.get('code')
         state=request.args.get('state')
         ----
```

pls help..

Comment: you are doing it in reverse... Flask api's can be called async using javascript and you can perform the operations. can't call a java script from flask, unless you are rendering a template and passing the {{}} variables to the JS code! Go through http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/jquery/ where it explains how to make AJAX calls with jQuery and Flask...

Answer (score 0):

The python script should go like this

```
 app = Flask(__name__)
 @app.route('/',methods=["GET","POST"])
 def index():
    script = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_token = request.args.get("validationtoken")
        print "search", search_token
        if search_token != None:
           # text = search_token
           resp = Response(search_token, status=200, mimetype='plain/text')
           print "resp",resp
           return resp
        else:
           print " Notification 
           script = True
           render_template('index.html', Script=script)



    elif request.method=="GET":
        code=request.args.get('code')
        state=request.args.get('state')
     ----
```

And the index.html should be something like this

```
{% if Script %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
     "Your code lies here"
    </script>
```

You can pass the variable in your python script (Your app) to the index.html template using this way as Flask uses Jinja templates.

Comment: Hi,in elif condition the render_template has applied already. This is not rendering.

Comment: But once it follow the following pattern i.e  if (POST) --> else then how it is going to the elif section of the code?